# C# -> Index was out of range error | Using Lists

Tags: c#, list, count, xna

I am using XNA to make a tank game. I've implemented a feature to shoot bullets using a list. After shooting, I want to test if the bullet has gotten close to the boundaries of the screen. If so, remove that particular bullet from the list.

The error appears only when I have more than one bullet on the screen at any given time. Here is the code:

---

Tank Class:

```
List<Bullet> bulletList = new List<Bullet>();
bool spacebarPrepared = true;    //for shooting every 0.5 seconds
short count = 0;


//Shoot
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && spacebarPrepared == true)
   {
        bulletList.Add(new Bullet(sprBullet, position, turretDirection, turretAngle));
        spacebarPrepared = false;
   }


if (spacebarPrepared == false)
    {
        spacebarCount += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        if (spacebarCount > 0.5)
        {
            spacebarPrepared = true;
            spacebarCount = 0;
        }
    }


//Update bullets
foreach (Bullet bullet in bulletList)
{
    bullet.Update(bounds);
}


count = (short)bulletList.Count;

//Remove unwanted bullets
for (short i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (bulletList[i].Alive == false)
    {
        bulletList.Remove(bulletList[i]);
    }
 }
```

Bullet Class:

```
class Bullet
{
    Texture2D spr;
    Vector2 origin, pos, dir, turretLength;
    float rotation, scale, turretLeng;
    short speed;
    bool alive = true;


    public Bullet(Texture2D sprite, Vector2 position, Vector2 direction, float angle)
    {
        spr = sprite;
        scale = 0.15f;
        turretLeng = (110 + spr.Width) * scale;
        speed = 5;
        rotation = angle;
        pos = position;
        dir = direction;
        origin = new Vector2(spr.Width / 2, spr.Height / 2);
        FindTurretLength();
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        Matrix bulletTranslation = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos.X + turretLength.X, pos.Y + turretLength.Y, 0);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, null, null, null, null, null, bulletTranslation);
        spriteBatch.Draw(spr, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White, 0, origin, 0.15f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }

    public void Update(Vector2 boundary)
    {
        pos += dir * speed;


        if (pos.X < 50 || pos.X > boundary.X - 50 || pos.Y < 50 || pos.Y > boundary.Y - 50)
        {
            alive = false;
        }
    }

    public void FindTurretLength()
    {
        turretLength = new Vector2(turretLeng * dir.X, turretLeng * dir.Y);
    }

    public Vector2 Pos
    {
        get
        {
            return pos;
        }
        set
        {
            pos = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Alive
    {
        get
        {
            return alive;
        }
        set
        {
            alive = value;
        }
    }
}
```

What I noticed myself when debugging was that my own 'count' variable = 2, yet the bulletList.Count = 1. Could that be the problem? How is that occurring?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this error happens when you try to access an element in a list or array that is higher than the count of items in said list. you should be able to figure out where this is happening by debugging and examining the line it's being thrown on, then working backwards and stepping through to see how the code is executing.

Comment: As an aside, why are you declaring `count` as a `short`? It seems `int` would be more natural.

Comment: What part of the exception did you not understand?  Visual Studio will show a link whilst debugging for more help online

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you guys. The problem is solved now.

@PeterDuniho: Short is more efficient. Just getting into habit of using it where possible. Only a beginner programmer

Comment: As a beginner programmer, you may be interested to learn that at best, `short` is more efficient in use of space, and even that is not assured depending on context. It's not a natural size of data on a modern CPU, and so can actually slow things down. In any case, its use here complicates the code; you should stick with the data types that fit the use at hand, to keep the code simpler. Only deviate if and when you have a _known_ performance problem and can show that a less-convenient implementation fixes that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Thanks very much for that bit of info. I'll certainly keep that in mind. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your for loop that removes bullets.

Lets say you have a list of 10 bullets (indexes 0 - 9) when you start the loop. The 1st bullet (at index 0) gets removed....now your list has 9 bullets (indexes 0 - 8), but the count variable has not been updated so your for loop still thinks it has 10.

When you reach the point where "i" is greater than the ACTUAL amount of bullets alive, you'll get the "Index was out of range." error.

There are multiple ways you can fix this error.

I would go for:

```
bulletList.RemoveAll(x => !x.Alive);
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer. I accepted AlexD's answer as he was quicker on the uptake. Thanks!

Comment: @meestaman Don't accept an answer based on how quick somebody is, but on quality.

Comment: @Kaz: Both answers explained and solved my problem. This is why I opted for the quicker person. But seeing as this question may help others in the future, I have changed my 'accepted answer' to yours as it is a little easier to understand, and gives a compact solution to the problem.